# Can I create a Google Drive folder using service account with Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I can create a folder using account Owner but cannot share it with service account.

Is there a way for My Python script to create a folder using service account and then upload a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder and upload file, same process flow as a real user when you using a service account.

#### BUT

As stated in this [blog](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2015/03/understanding-service-accounts.html), you have to remember that:

> A service account is a sort of virtual user or robot account associated with a given project. It has an email address, and a cryptographic key pair.

Also, there is a statement from a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22247317/5995040) that:

> There is no UI for Service Accounts. The files are only accessible to your app.

I suggest that you share a folder from a real account to your service account so that accessing the files would be easier.

Hope this help!

Comment: Great points, thanx. The only way to share afolder I know is to use email of service account right? If yes - I cannot do it because by company policy I can share folders only with **@company.com emails.

Comment: AFAIK - yes, you have to share it using the email of the service account. If that is the case, you will only be able to view the files using the application connected to the service account.