# upload file to google drive without human interaction via SDK

Tags: file-upload, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, authorization

I want to upload files to google drive. I'm using C# and have referred following links to get started

1. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet
2. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

I'm able to upload the file successfully to google drive but my main concern is I don't want to display any sort of UI/human interaction. It should be able to automatically upload the file.

Using OAuth2.0 there is a need that we have to manage and generate access/refresh token. I have no idea how these should be managed.

Isn't there any other way where the user can have access to google drive programmatically just by sharing his/her Gmail account username/password to achieve this?

Comment: You can use service account to upload your files. Daimto's tutorial on [Google Drive API with a Service Account](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/) and [Automated Google Drive File Backup](http://www.instructables.com/id/Automated-Google-Drive-File-Backup-Python-Google-A/) best explain how to use service account for using Drive APi and Service Account. You can also check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848117/5995040) regarding creating folder from Drive API with service account. Be aware that you need to share the files to your account to gain access to it

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for pointing this out. You can use this for a central account and not to bypass OAuth for multiple access. Thanks again

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I tried using the C# library and found that I have to authorize the app only for the first time. Later on when the access/refresh token is expired library automatically regenerates the token for me.

This is what i found after testing it for 2 days. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Isn't there any other way where the user can have access to google drive programmatically just by sharing his/her Gmail account username/password to achieve this?**

No there is not

The user needs to authorise your app one time. After that, you can save  Refresh Token and use that for future unattended use.

Comment: As far as I know, access/refresh token is automatically refreshed and we don't have to do anything once the app is authorized for the fist time. Is that true?

Comment: some of the libraries might or might not refresh the token. It's a simple single REST call, so personally I'd do it myself.