# Use one Google Drive account as central repository in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to develop an app where different users will take pictures and those pictures will be uploaded to one centralised Google Drive account. Now problem is that when I integrate Google Drive SDK with android, it's process is to ask each user for their credentials but I want only one credentials to be used and it should automatically connect to Google Drive when app is started.

I tried different SDK methods but it isn't working actually it is supposed to work like that. Like the one I tried is the below one but it has process of asking user for credentials, but I do not want that I want predefined user_account and password to be used.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

So, does SDK support it? And I looked at Google Drive API too it also first asking me to connect to google drive with my current account installed.

Comment: Try using a service account for uploading, this will make your app use a central account and it is not for multiple users (see related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46066239/5995040) for reference). **OR** simply use a constant parentID when uploading a file, that way it will also be shared to the users but you'll use multiple account. Hope this helps.

Comment: The app must request at least one user authorization to use Google Drive, so you have to implement user picker in the first usage and remember the account (google-drive-sdk do it for you).